# Creating a file using Wso2Esb getting stuck

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

Hi am working with Wso2Esb 4.7.0

I have created a proxy which creates a file in the local system, Below is the proxy and its sequence, I have uncommented the required vfs transport in axis2 file.

Proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="FileProxy"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <property name="Body"
                   expression="$body"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                   expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.txt')"
                   scope="transport"/>
     <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <Reading>$1</Reading>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Body')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
          <send receive="fileWriteSequence">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="vfs:file:///home/youtility/Documents/Capp_services/wso2esb-4.7.0/Files"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         </inSequence>
      <outSequence onError="fault">
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="fileWriteSequence">
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="sequence" value="fileWriteSequence"/>
   </log>
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
         <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
            <Body>
               <Datalist>file Created</Datalist>
            </Body>
            <Status>200</Status>
         </ResponseJSON>
      </format>
      <args/>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send/>
</sequence>
```

curl:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"test1":"1","test2":"-1","test3":"-1"}' http://localhost:8282/services/FileProxy
```

When am trying to call this service with the curl file is getting created in the mentioned file location with the given content but am not getting any response as **file Created** as mentioned in the sequence, Actually after creating the file the process is not going the the fileWriteSequence so it is getting stuck.

Any Suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

You are in OUT_ONLY, (you have set `<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>`) and you must be in OUT_ONLY when you create a file because there is no response from the filesystem

Therefore, the "receive" sequence will never be executed : add it's content after the send mediator

Comment: Hi Jean i have removed the out only property from the service and executed  i got an error as  ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The VFS transport doesn't support synchronous responses. Please use the appropriate (out only) message exchange pattern.

Comment: Is there any way that we can make VFS as synchronous and get response with out using OUT_only...?

Comment: I don't think so (or use last version of WSO2 ESB : 4.9.0). But I'm not sure to understand the problem : the content of your "fileWriteSequence" can be moved inside the in sequence, after send (just think to transform your REQUEST in RESPONSE using <header name="To" action="remove"/>
    <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
    <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>)